# How to avoid use of oracle.sql.StructDescriptor and oracle.sql.STRUCT statement in java code?

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

*How can we map PL/SQL type object and java object by avoiding use of oracle.sql.StructDescriptor and oracle.sql.STRUCT statements. 
As i search on many sites, even JPA also internally use StructDescriptor and STRUCT to map SQL type and java objects. I don't want to go for hibernate framework.Is it any alternative provided in java?*

Comment: There is the JDBC DatabaseMetaData on the connection object.

Comment: Thanks for reply....Actaully i have already written procedures that accept PL/SQL type object. Now, i have java object similar to PL/SQL type object.So i have to make consistency between java and PL/SQL type object. Once i call procedure passing java object as parameter then PL/SQL code should consider this parameter as PL/SQL type object.